# Rails Routes: Cleaner if statement with authenticate block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

Is there a cleaner way to write this? Like using an OR instead of an if statement?

```
 if Rails.env.development?
     mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  else
    authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
      mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of readability this is already clean and understandable code.
You can of course write it like this:

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| Rails.env.development? || u.admin?  } do
   mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

The only difference with this shorter notation is that you are always calling the `authenticate` method.

Comment: I tried this before posting ,but this authenticates before checking the development env.  In development it should not need to authenticate.